# Handling error in http calls in ionic 2

Tags: http, ionic-framework, promise, ionic2

In my Ionic2 app, I have a service which handles all http requests.
I have an alert controller when any error occurs in http call. On button click in this alert I want to run that call again. I am able to do it right now. The problem is response is not resolved to page from which function was called.

Code in service:

```
loadCity(){
return new Promise(resolve => {
this.http.get(url).map(res=>res.json())
.subscribe(data => {resolve(data)},
err => { this.showAlert(err); }
});
}

showAlert(err: any){
// code for alert controller, I am only writing handler of alert 
//controller refresh button
handler => {this.loadCity();}
}
```

Code in CityPage

```
showCity(){
this.cityService.loadCity()
.then(data => {//process data});
}
```

Handler is calling function again but this time promise is not resolved to CityPage showCity() function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an error occurs in the http request, the error callback function is being called, but you are neither resolving nor rejecting the promise.

You can do something like

```
loadCity(){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(url).map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => {resolve(data)},
            err => { 
                this.showAlert(err);
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and in the caller

```
showCity(){
    this.cityService.loadCity()
    .then( data => {
        //process data
    })
    .catch( error => {
        //some error here
    })
}
```

You can see better examples in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. My bad, I am new & I coded without knowing basics.